# Pandas - Align matching column values to row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have what appears to be a simple problem, that I was not able to find a solution to. Namely, I have a table, where first column contains the list of all available applications, while other columns represent users and the list of applications they have:

[image]

I'm trying to convert the table into pandas DataFrame and align matching values on the first column. The desired output should look like this:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('U:/Desktop/appdata.xlsx')

df.head(10)
Out[21]: 
  Applications User 1 User 2 User 3 User 4 User 5
0         App1   App1   App2   App1   App1   App2
1         App2   App3   App3   App2   App3   App3
2         App3  App10   App4   App7   App4   App4
3         App4    NaN   App5   App8   App5   App5
4         App5    NaN    NaN  App10   App6   App6
5         App6    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   App7
6         App7    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   App8
7         App8    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   App9
8         App9    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
9        App10    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN

df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Applications'] == x, axis=1)]
Out[22]: 
  Applications User 1 User 2 User 3 User 4 User 5
0         App1   App1    NaN   App1   App1    NaN
1         App2    NaN    NaN   App2    NaN    NaN
2         App3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3         App4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4         App5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
5         App6    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
6         App7    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
7         App8    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
8         App9    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
9        App10    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: My opinion would be correct this at the source. Interpretation of having scalable rows and columns is correct, but while marking the values just mark a binary against each application, i.e. `(App1, User1) = 1 and (App2, User1) = 0`. This way you could compute easily. Also try to avoid spaces in column names.

Comment: @Vishnudev - I greatly appreciate the feedback, and you are quite correct, it would be better to "binarise" the values, however, that would require work on the data beforehand (since the format in the question is how data is delivered to me)

Comment: The source does mater. My feedback is only valid if you could control the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with some numpy tools. Here, `apply` loops through the columns of interest, `np.isin` performs a search over your first column (dat.Applications) and returns True if the respective element is contained in the current column. This boolean array is then converted to the respective string in dat.Applications or to NAN if there is no match via `np.where`. The results are then assigned back to the original DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np

dat.iloc[:, 1:] = \
dat.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x : np.where(np.isin(dat.Applications, x),
                                          dat.Applications, np.NAN))
```

Note that it would work to use pd.`np.isin` for instance rather than directly importing numpy, but this seems a bit cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

A key observation is that in the output, a value in the column of the application also represents the value for that row (index col == value col)

```
(df.iloc[:,1:]
   .melt()
   .dropna()
   .pivot(index='value',columns='variable',values='value')
   .reindex([f'App{x}' for x in range(1,11)]))
```